# Problem installing Shoutpy + Boost.python on opensolaris

Tags: python, boost, boost-python, opensolaris

Im trying to install shoutpy on opensolaris 2009.6. It relies on boost.python. i've installed the `boost_devel` libraries from blastwave and linked `/opt/csw/include/boost` to `/usr/include/boost` . But when I try to `easy_install shoutpy` I get the following output

```
munderwo@opensolaris-test1:/usr/include$ pfexec easy_install shoutpy
Searching for shoutpy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/shoutpy/
Reading http://dingoskidneys.com/shoutpy/
Best match: shoutpy 1.0.0
Downloading http://dingoskidneys.com/shoutpy/shoutpy-1.0.0.tar.gz
Processing shoutpy-1.0.0.tar.gz
Running shoutpy-1.0.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-w7XQfv/shoutpy-1.0.0/egg-dist-tmp-k11Dky
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object/make_ptr_instance.hpp:8,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from shoutpy.cc:26:
/usr/include/boost/python/object/instance.hpp:44: error: a casts to a type other than an integral or enumeration type cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/include/boost/python/object/instance.hpp:44: error: '->' cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/include/boost/python/object/instance.hpp:44: error: `&' cannot appear in a constant-expression
In file included from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/registry.hpp:9,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/registered.hpp:8,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object/make_instance.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object/make_ptr_instance.hpp:8,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/to_python_indirect.hpp:11,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/converter/arg_to_python.hpp:10,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/call.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/object_core.hpp:12,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python/args.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/python.hpp:11,
                 from shoutpy.cc:26:
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/rvalue_from_python_data.hpp:99: error: '->' cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/rvalue_from_python_data.hpp:99: error: `&' cannot appear in a constant-expression
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/rvalue_from_python_data.hpp:99: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/include/boost/python/converter/rvalue_from_python_data.hpp:99: error: `value' is not a member of `<declaration error>'
error: Setup script exited with error: command '/usr/lib/python2.6/pycc' failed with exit status 1
```

This is using python2.6, opensolaris 2009.06, boost 1.35.

any help would be great!

Cheers

Mark

Edit - this has been cross posted on serverfault as its a bit hard to classify where the problem domain is. https://serverfault.com/questions/88724/problem-with-opensolaris-boost-python-and-shoutpy

Comment: I wrote that software. Try sending the author an e-mail asking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I've never tried to compile `shoutpy` under OpenSolaris and I don't use it these days. Boost.python requires a lot from its C++ compiler. Use `easy_install -b build_directory shoutpy` so it'll keep the source code after it fails, then check the C++ compiler Python tries to use against those supported by boost.python.

I tried compiling it on my desktop Linux and it still works after I edit `setup.py` to link against `libboost_python-mt` instead of `libboost_python` which doesn't exist in Ubuntu (there are several `libboost_python*` depending on Python version and so forth).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You say you wrote that software. You wrote Shoutpy? As to the compiler im using gcc im pretty sure. What is the difference between libboost-python-mt and libboost-python?

Comment: I wrote shoutpy. The mt in libboost-python-mt stands for multithreading, iow it can be used with Python code that uses threads.

Comment: well thats convenient. I guess i'll send you an email. I hope the one on the shoutpy website is upto date :)